# Different conventions for Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, differential-topology, index-theory

I seem to find a disparity by a factor of 2 in some results where the Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch theorem is used. I am particularly troubled by the following example; in https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.2786 (page 10) it is shown that the index of a particular Cauchy-Riemann operator is
\begin{equation}
\textrm{index} (\phi^{\ast}\nabla^A)^{0,1}  =  \langle c^G_1(TX),\phi_*(\Sigma)\rangle  +  (\textrm {dim}_\mathbb{C} X)(1-g).
\end{equation}
However, in the related paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0111176.pdf (page 28),
the index for this operator is given as 
\begin{equation}
\textrm{index} (\phi^{\ast}\nabla^A)^{0,1}  =  2\langle c^G_1(TX),\phi_*(\Sigma)\rangle  +  (\textrm {dim}_\mathbb{C} X)(2-2g).
\end{equation}
Why is there an additional factor of 2 in the second expression? Is it a case of different conventions, or are the operators in the two references actually different?

Comment: Without looking at the papers...is it possible that one is discussing the real index, and the other the complex index?

Comment: I suppose this is a basic question, but what is the difference between the real index and complex index, is the first just two multiplied by the latter?

Comment: Yes; this is a fact about linear algebra. If you have a complex vector space of complex dimension n, then it is naturally a real vector space of (real) dimension 2n.  Eg your vector space might be the kernel or cokernel of a complex-linear operator....